# How do I print in columns in java with printf?

Tags: java, printf, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

```
Day         Car 1      Car 2
1           3800.20    2200.42
2           2700.67    3678.14
3           2900.00    2694.47
```

I've tried doing this in my for loop (the first line of code for the strings is outside of the for loop, but it looks the same just different variables):

```
System.out.printf("%6d %6d %6d",Day,Car1,Car2);
```

But I'm just getting errors. I'd like the columns to be left-aligned.

How would I do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: "But I'm just getting errors." - what errors? "%6d" - what you try to do with this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to pass floats or doubles in; you'd need %6.2f and not %6d for those, but, really, when asking questions on SO and reporting on what you tried, you need to show the full code AND add the exact error(s) you get, that makes it all a lot easier for us to help you :)

Comment: Please clearly indicate the errors, your input, your actual (not desired) output, and what you have tried (all the loop with printf statement).

Comment: %d refers to digits or integers in this case. If you want to format decimal numbers, you should use %f. Check this for further info: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the columns to the left, `-` has to be used in the formatting pattern because by default the numerical columns are aligned to the right:

```java
Object[][] a = {
    {1, 3800.20, 2200.42},
    {2, 2700.67, 3678.14},
    {3, 2900.00, 2694.47}
};
System.out.printf("%3s  %-9s  %-9s%n", "Day", "Car1", "Car2");
for (Object[] r : a) {
    System.out.printf("%-3d  %-9.2f  %-9.2f%n", r[0], r[1], r[2]);
}
```

Output:

```
Day  Car1       Car2     
1    3800.20    2200.42  
2    2700.67    3678.14  
3    2900.00    2694.47
```